# How to roll back new xcode projects to previous one?

Tags: xcode4.6, xcode5

I am facing such a critical thing which is i have updated my xcode from 4.6 to 5.0, now the problem is the project which runs once on 5.0 xcode is not running on 4.6 version please can anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: Why would you want to use Xcode 4.6 again?

Comment: because my other colleagues have that version!

Comment: eventually you'll have to fix the issues! In the meantime download 4.6 here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have opened the project on Xcode 5 the storyboards and nibs will default to opening in Xcode 5. Open the storyboard or nibs in the project and make sure you change the "Opens in" back to whatever version Xcode your team uses. Please advise if this does not resolve your issue or feel free to accept the answer if all is well.

[image: File Inspector]